# Prototype: How do I find the first element with a certain class?

Tags: css, prototypejs

I have 2 ul elements in my document. How can I find the first of the 2 using PrototypeJS? I tried this code:

```
first = $$('ul[class="level0"]')[0];
second = $$('ul[class="level0"]')[1];
```

Only first is filled, the second is empty. Any ideas? This is my html:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="level0 nav-1 first level-top parent">
        <ul class="level0">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level0 nav-2 last level-top parent">
        <ul class="level0">...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. An unclosed UL cannot be between two LIs.

Comment: Please check your code. Great mistake in your HTML code.

Comment: Yeah, thats because I copied it from Firebug ... lets assume the closing ul is there. I edited my post anyway.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uaHEm/ - everything you asked works

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the attribute CSS selector use the class CSS selector

```
first = $$('ul.level0')[0];
second = $$('ul.level0')[1];
```

but otherwise that should work

there are other methods as well `$$()` returns an array of elements (even if is one) and you can refer to the `.first()`

```
first = $$('ul.level0').first()
```

Please let us know if fixing the HTML worked or if you are getting any errors in your javascript console - that could lead you to a different problem

Answer (score 0):

Use

**first**

```
$('nav').down('.level0');
```

**second**

```
$('nav').down('.level0', 1);
```

Cheers